# calculate mean for cases that responded to a minimum number of items in R

Tags: r, spss

In SPSS you can calculate means for cases that responded to a minimum number of questions. In SPSS I would type

COMPUTE compvar = MEAN.4(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7).

And this would generate a new variable (i.e., compvar) only for cases that had a value present for 4 or more of the array var1 - var7. That's what the .4 is doing in the command, setting a minimum number of responses before the command will run for a case.

Any tips on doing this in R so I can stop jumping to SPSS?

Comment: Please provide example data for this question. Is each column a binary variable with Y/N and/or some kind of response? How is non-response denoted?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a built in function as far as I know - here's one you can try:

```
mycolmeans<-function(df,n){
  holding<-colMeans(df,na.rm=TRUE)
  holding[n > as.vector(colSums(!is.na(df)))]<-NA
  holding
}
```

This assumes you have a dataframe holding your values in columns, and you want an NA returned when it has too many missing values, which are denoted as NAs.

```
x <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), b = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5, 
6)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

mycolmeans(x,4)
mycolmeans(x,6)
```

Comment: In SPSS, MEAN.X takes the mean of the ROW, not the column. So this would not give him the answer he expects (colMeans).

Answer (score 2):

This could represent a possibility:

```
compvar <- sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x) ifelse(sum(!is.na(df[x,])*1)>=4, mean(as.numeric(df[x,]),na.rm=TRUE),NA))
```

I'm assuming that your numeric data is stored in a dataframe `df`. The output is a vector `compvar` of length nrow which contains either the mean of the corresponding row in `df`, or `NA` if there are less than four non-NA entries in that row.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you had a data.frame with 5 variables

```
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(c(NA,rnorm(5)),50,replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(c(NA,rnorm(5)),50,replace = TRUE),
  var3 = sample(c(NA,rnorm(5)),50,replace = TRUE),
  var4 = sample(c(NA,rnorm(5)),50,replace = TRUE),
  var5 = sample(c(NA,rnorm(5)),50,replace = TRUE)
)
```

I would calculate the mean for every row, first. The following command calculates the mean for every row, ignoring that the row has NA (99 in SPSS or simply "missing") values.

```
df$compvar <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Then I would set those responses where the number of NA is greater than X (in this example, 1). This converts the data.frame into a TRUE FALSE fields that you can take a simple rowSum of, and set to a condition.

```
df[rowSums(sapply(df, is.na)) > 1,]$compvar <- NA
```

You should look over each of the following to garner an understanding of what is being provided at each step:

```
sapply(df, is.na)
rowSums(sapply(df, is.na))
rowSums(sapply(df, is.na)) > 1
df[rowSums(sapply(df, is.na)) > 1,]
```

As a funciton, this could be written as:

```
#' Row means with minimum response
#' 
#' Emulates SPSS MEAN.X functionality
#' @param df A data.frame
#' @param x The number of responses required per row.
#' @export
meanx <- function(df,x) { 
  df$compvar <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
  df[rowSums(sapply(df, is.na)) > x,]$compvar <- NA
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See `mean_n()` in the [sjmisc-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjmisc/index.html).

```
mean_n(data, 4)
```